# How are individual instructions and their input operands stored in memory?

Tags: assembly, cpu, ram, machine-code, instructions

Are the individual processor instructions simply the first "x amount of"bits and then the input operands just some other "x amount of"bits adjacent and contiguous after the instruction in memory? Does every instruction implicitly require a certain amount of bits to be set after their defining bit sequence given the amount of input operands needed for such instruction in memory? Or are instructions and their operands stored in some other way(if so how are they associated)?

Comment: You mean bytes not bits.

Comment: I mean, there are alwats 8 bits in a byte, I just use bits interchangeably here.

Comment: plus, I wouldnt know to say "byte" singular or "bytes" plural so bits fits both forms.(im not familiar with how instructions are stored, how many bytes they occupy, etc)

Comment: The term you're looking for is *instruction encoding*.  Every CPU architecture does it in a different way, but yes, in general an instruction is encoded as some contiguous sequence of bytes.  On some architectures it's the same number of bytes for every instruction, on others instructions can have variable length.  You should be able to find tables showing the encoding scheme for your favorite architecture.

Comment: Just a quick answer, I am not an expert in assembly. The instruction pointer points to the address of the current instruction. The CPU fetches the next instruction from that address along with the relevant operands. The IP is then incremented accordingly unless it is a jump instruction.

Comment: @NateEldredge if you would like to expand a bit(<-see what I did there) on your comment and also explain it fully in an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I will try if I have some time later.  Is there a particular architecture you want to focus on?  How much do you know about assembly language and your machine's instruction set?

Comment: @NateEldredge x86 is ok. I would say I know the basics of assembly and also the basics of how the cpu works, with some greater knowledge inherent to knowing c++ added into that.

Comment: The x86 is a bit like an interpreter. The first byte of the code is examined to find out what to read or do next. Some instructions are always 1 byte such as `AAA`. Not all modes of an instruction use the same number of bytes. A simple example is the `DEC` instruction. If the first byte is `01001xxx` then it is a 1 byte instruction with the register operand coded in `xxx`. But if the first byte is `1111111w` then it is a memory operation and the `w` bit tells how to proceed. If `w` is `0` then it is a byte instruction, otherwise a word instruction, and the next byte tells more.

Comment: bits is the correct term, not bytes as there are many instruction sets whose instruction length is not a multiple of 8 bits. the instruction set is just part of a system design that includes the bus interfaces and fetching so the instructions, whatever size, are not going to be bit sliced across memory locations 7 bits of a byte the the one but plus 6 more bits from the next byte, remaining 2 bits and 5 bits from the next byte.   While possible and perhaps someone did this, is not common.

Comment: @Tarik There have been CPUs in the past (most notably, the iAPX-432) where instructions comprised individual bits.

Comment: @fuz There is a saying you know? "The exception proves the rule" ;-)